# How do I read a file to a list in python?

Tags: python, file

I have a file delimited by space
Eg.

```
1 1 2
1 2 3
2 2 3
1 1 3
```

I want to put each line into a list hence creating a list of lists. I want to omit the first column of the file and I want to convert the type to Integer so that I can perform integer operations on it. Therefore the list for the about example should look like [ [1, 2], [2, 3] , [ 2, 3] , [1, 3] ]
Code I have used is listed below.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        f = open("Ai.txt")
        next(f)
        self.coordinates = []
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            if count == 274:
                break
            else:
                self.coordinates.append([ int(i) for i in line.split()[1:] ])
                count += 1


    def getLocation( self, vertex ):
        return self.coordinates[vertex]

g = Graph()
x = g.getLocation(44)
print x
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
zip(*zip(*csv.reader(open("my_file.txt"),delimiter=" "))[1:])
```

if you need ints you can just wrap it in some maps

```
map(lambda x:map(int,x),zip(*zip(*csv.reader(open("my_file.txt"),delimiter=" "))[1:]))
```

Comment: Forgot to convert to int... also, do you really need that inner `list`?

Comment: im not entirely sure if you can unpack without it ... so i went with the sure bet of using it (the `list`) ... and I was too lazy to try ... but im gonna find out now

Comment: and the answer is no I do not need that :P

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('/path/to/file') as f:
    x = [[int(i) for i in l.split()[1:]] for l in f if l.strip()]
print(x)
# Outputs: 
# [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = """1 1 2
1 2 3
2 2 3
1 1 3"""

result = [map(int,line.split(" ")[1:]) for line in a.split("\n")]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

PS: I let you handle the file part :P

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def col(row):
    for item in row.split()[1:]:
        yield int(item)

def row(fp):
    for row in fp:
        yield list(col(row))

with open("input.txt") as fp:
    result = list(row(fp))

print result
```